# Applying Tailwind overflow behavior to only one child element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind to style a React component called "BlurImage" which displays an image by default and then on hover removes the image and displays a button at the bottom of the component and a text box at the top that has overflow-y-auto behavior to allow for scrolling if the text grows too long.

By default, the overflow responsibility is given to the body as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309413/in-tailwindcss-why-is-my-flex-1-element-overflowing-the-height-of-the-parent-el) and so I need to give the parent top-level div of BlurImage `overflow` as well. This causes both the text and the button to be scrollable. Is there a way to avoid having the button scroll?

This seems like it should be a common situation - I can imagine using this concept to write self-contained components that have a header/footer and some scrollable content as well. Unfortunately, I can't find much addressing this in the Tailwind docs or online.

I appreciate any suggestions! Here is the component code that I currently have:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import cn from 'classnames';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ImageInfo } from '../../types/images';
import Button from './button';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

type BlurImageProps = {
    image: ImageInfo;
};

const BlurImage = ({ image }: BlurImageProps): JSX.Element => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div className="group shrink-0 h-40 w-40 relative aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 overflow-hidden rounded-lg xl:aspect-w-7 xl:aspect-h-8 drop-shadow-xl bg-black">
            <Image
                alt=""
                src={image.url}
                width={512}
                height={512}
                className={cn(
                    'flex h-full duration-700 ease-in-out group-hover:opacity-20',
                    {
                        'scale-110 blur-2xl grayscale': isLoading,
                        'scale-100 blur-0 grayscale-0': !isLoading,
                    },
                )}
                onLoadingComplete={() => setLoading(false)}
            />
            {!isLoading && (
                <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 overflow-y-scroll items-center justify-center w-full h-full align-middle text-center px-2 opacity-0 duration-700 ease-in-out group-hover:opacity-100">
                    <a href={image.url}>
                        <p className="text-base text-white mb-2">
                            {image.prompt}
                        </p>
                    </a>

                    <Button
                        className="flex-shrink-0 px-2 py-2 text-sm font-bold text-white rounded bg-green-500"
                        type="button"
                        text="click me"
                        isSubmit={true}
                        onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default BlurImage;
```